# How do I rerun cloud-init without shutting down?

Tags: cloud-init, google-container-os

Is there a recommended way of running cloud-init on Google Container-Optimized OS once the instance is up and have it fetch the latest metadata?

So far, I have been blowing away the /var/lib/cloud/instances directory and rerunning, but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) images, there is `/usr/share/cloud/rerun-cloudinit.sh` that you can run. It will re-fetch the latest metadata and run all required cloud-init steps.